# What is Chtholly?

Tags: worldend

What is Chtholly in the literal sense?

In episode 7 (Home Sweet Home), it is shown that Chtholly undergoes some changes due to her meeting with Elq Hrqstn. She is proven no longer a Fairy (Leprenchauns) as Silver test fails.

If a Fairy is basically part of Elq's soul that still large enough and becomes an independent entity, does this make Chtholly a Visitor? Or is she a human? But a human requires the 'beast' aspect which she does not have.